how to simulate syn flood sing INET
I am trying to simulate a SYN flood attack, but I am not sure how to achieve this. I have attempted to use TcpSessionApp and TcpSinkApp, but the targeted host is sending back SYN-ACK responses, which is not the desired behavior for a SYN flood attack. Additionally, the simulation finishes quickly. Is there an existing example or a more appropriate method to simulate a SYN flood attack that I could reference to better understand how to set this up correctly?
